# Missunderstood call to Python requests-oauthlib .fetch_token()

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an OAuth2 authenticated Python-based service where I use [requests-oauthlib](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to do the authentication.

My authentication seems to work mostly fine for many users, but I also get quite a few errors reporting `'invalid grant'` errors and I'm having some difficulties to find out why. The authorization is heavily inspired by the [examples](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/google.html) in the requests-oauthlib documentation.

The auth URL is constructed like this:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
session = OAuth2Session(
    os.environ['GOOGLE_SIGNIN_CLIENTID'],
    scope=[
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
        ],
    redirect_uri=<the redirect URL>,
    state=<a custom serialized state>)
auth_url = session.authorization_url(
    "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    access_type="offline",
    login_hint=email or '',
    state=<a custom serialized state>
    )[0]
```

Auth responses works well and comes back to my service. But at the OAuth2 callback, and many authentications works good. At the callback endpoint I re-construct the `Oauth2Session` object as below:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
session = OAuth2Session(
    os.environ['GOOGLE_SIGNIN_CLIENTID'],
    scope=[
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
        ],
    redirect_uri=<the redirect URL>,
    state=<a custom serialized state>)
```

And requests a token:

```
token = session.fetch_token(
    "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    client_secret=os.environ['GOOGLE_SIGNIN_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    authorization_response=request.url)
```

Around 1/3 of the attempts result in a traceback ending in:

```
line 271, in raise_from_error
    raise cls(**kwargs)
InvalidGrantError: (invalid_grant)
```

Does anyone see something familiar? Could I be missing some  important parameter to `.fetch_token()`?

**Update 22 december 2015:**
I started to suspect that the `auth_url` was not in the providers list of approved authentication URL's, so I investigated the app and found that the callback resource can be accessed via two different URL's (although they are fetched from the same environment variable). I added the alternative URL to the Google Developer's console and initially it looked like that was the case. Unfortunately an identical error arrived a bit later so it looks like that suspicion was wrong.

Comment: figure out how to trace the http. There will be some additional information in the http response.